# Msbuild properties

Tags: msbuild

I have been recently sifting through MSBuild documentation trying to find other valid properties that can be passed to the task, and so far have been drawing up a blank on a centralized listing.

I believe that VCBuildAdditionalOptions & BuildCmd are both valid parameters, however does anybody know where there are any further valid properties listed?

Comment: are you talking about flags against MSBUILD.exe, or properties defined inside an MsBuild script, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you're looking for? [Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)

For TeamBuild, there's the [WwW version](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000374.html) and the [Aaron Hallberg's Team Build 2008 Property Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/02/12/team-build-2008-property-reference.aspx).